# Can I upload the code and the deploying one in the same repository in GitHub?

Tags: reactjs, deployment, github-pages

I have deployed my react project to GitHub pages. Also, I want to upload the original code to another branch, thereby share the code link and deployed link separately in Linkedin. But when I'm doing this, only HTML is showing as 100% in the languages.

Should I upload the code and the deploying one separately in 2 repositories? How can I solve that language error?

Answer (score 0):

From your question what I understood is, if you want to share your code just make the code branch `default` one, not the build branch. That should take care of the problem. 
And unfortunately, GitHub language option is by default. You can't do anything about it.